# Unable to create Kafka DealLetterTopic using DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to create a dead letter topic using DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer but unable to create it.
Below are the beans that i am defining.

But i see in the logs that in the ProducerConfig, i dont see the property allow.auto.create.topics. Its missing and then the DLT topic doesnot get created.

Can someone please suggest?

```
@Autowired
    private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

@Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> produceFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Object> defaultKafkaProducerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(
                configProps);
        return defaultKafkaProducerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemp() {
    MessagingMessageConverter messageConverter = new MessagingMessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setHeaderMapper(new SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper("*")); // map all byte[] headers
    KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    kafkaTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    return kafkaTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaOperations<String, Object> getKafkaTemplate() { // producer to DLQ
        return kafkaTemp();
    }

    @Bean
    public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer() {
        return new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(getKafkaTemplate());
    }

    @Bean
    public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler seekToCurrentErrorHandler(
            DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer, OfferRESTClient offerRestClient) {
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
                deadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(record, exception);
            }
        });
        errorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true);
        errorHandler.setBackOffFunction((record, exception) -> {
            return new FixedBackOff(0L, 5L;
        });
        return errorHandler;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`allow.auto.create.topics` is a broker property, not a client property. You typically won't want to use that because it might not get the required number of partitions.

The framework does not automatically provision dead letter topics, you must create them yourself, or add a `NewTopic` `@Bean` and Spring will create it for you.

See [Configuring Topics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#configuring-topics).

Also see [Publishing Dead-letter Records](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#dead-letters).

> By default, the dead-letter record is sent to a topic named `<originalTopic>.DLT` (the original topic name suffixed with .DLT) and to the same partition as the original record. Therefore, when you use the default resolver, the dead-letter topic must have at least as many partitions as the original topic.

Comment: Thankyou but i am confused because... with the same setup as above without defining the bean for the topic... the deadletterpublisher is creating a topic on its own in my local kafka cluster.... but the same setup when i am trying in another environment then it doesnot work... can you please throw some light on it?

Comment: `>... another environment...` - that broker/cluster likely doesn't have `allow.auto.create.topics` set to true.

Comment: it does because we are able to create the topic from command line but not from the code... and this same code creates the topic in local cluster

Comment: `>we are able to create the topic from command line` Which command line tool? `kafka-topics` or `kafka-console-producer`? I have seen a race condition sometimes. As I said, you need to make sure the topic has the right number of partitions anyway, so add a `NewTopic` bean. Most admins don't allow auto-created topics on the broker.

Comment: we are able to create from command line using kafka-topics? so when we do from the framework that doesnot use kafka-topics?

Comment: Using `kafka-topics` is not auto-creating a topic, it is explicitly creating a topic. auto-creation is when you publish to a topic that doesn't exist and, if the broker is so configured, the broker creates it for you. The framework does not use the command-line tool; it detects any `NewTopic` beans and uses the `kafka-clients` `AdminClient` to create the topics with the configured number of partitions and replicas (and other properties).

Comment: I see.. that makes sense... and yes when i added as new bean then i was able to create the topic... that helps alot... thankyou so much